# Adding values to an arraylist with setters

Tags: java, logic

Arraylist not taking correct user input. I want the array to store the student's name and then id,
so the output should be [boris,22]. 
but this is the output I'm receiving

Enter Student name boris

[boris]

Enter ID 22

[boris, boris]

I know I could just assign a variable to the user input and add that to the ArrayList, but I'd like to use a setter to do it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;

public class studentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Student> storage = new ArrayList<Student>(); 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Student obj3 = new Student();

        System.out.print("Enter Student name ");

        obj3.setName(input.nextLine());
        storage.add(obj3);
        System.out.print(storage);
        System.out.print("Enter ID ");
        obj3.setID(input.nextInt());
        storage.add(obj3);

        System.out.print(storage);
    }
}

public class Student {

    private  String  name;
    private int ID;
    private double grade;
    private int test;
    private int NUM_Tests;

    public Student() {
        name = "unassigned";
        ID = 0;
        grade = 0;
        test = 0;
        NUM_Tests = 0;
    }

    public  void setName(String N) { 
        name = N;   
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setID(int I) {
        ID = I;
    }
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public String toString() { 
        return String.format(name,ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: `private static String  name;`??? That field should definitely ***not*** be static, nor should any getters or setters

Comment: Remove all the  `static` in Student class, test again and tell us please;)

Comment: Also, no need to re-add obj3 to the list. You've added it once, and that's enough

Comment: `return String.format(name,ID);` should be `return String.format("%s %d", name, ID);`

Comment: Okay code updated, no statics, still the same issue.

Comment: Fix the format, the probelm was, you add **twice** the same object obj3 and your toString method return only the name, so you see twice the name;) I think you may close your post once you fix all of this ;)

Comment: Yep , elliot, changed the format, but still not fully fixed from that, I was then getting [boris, 0] enter id : 22 [boris 22, boris 22] so i did what hovercraft said and deleted the first storage.add(obj3) and together it worked. thank you guys

Comment: Can you update your code on the post, please?

Comment: And in case no one of those, who posted their replies are willing to post an answer, that satisfies the question, could you please write a short one and mark it as the right answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change to string in student class:
`return String.format(name,ID);` should be `return String.format("%s %d", name, ID);`

- Courtesy of Elliot

And remove the first `storage.add(obj3)` which was causing the duplicate.

- Courtesy of Hovercraft and Azro

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;

public class studentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Student> storage = new ArrayList<>(); 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Student student;

        System.out.println("Create student. Type 0 to exit!");

        while(input.nextLine() != "0") {

            student = new Student();

            System.out.print("Enter the name: ");
            student.setName(input.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter ID: ");
            student.setID(input.nextInt());

            storage.add(student);
        }

        for (Student s: storage) {
            System.out.print( s.toString() );
        }
    }
}

public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int ID;
    private double grade;
    private int test;
    private int NUM_Tests;

    //Constructor
    public Student() {

        name = "unassigned";
        ID = 0;
        grade = 0;
        test = 0;
        NUM_Tests = 0;
    }

    //Getter and Setter
    //.....
    //.....

    public String toString() {
        String s = "Student info ----\n" + 
            "Name: " + this.name + "\n" + 
                "ID: " + this.ID + "\n" +
                    "---------------\n";
        return s;
    }
}
```

Using this code, you can insert more than one student in your `List`. If you want to stop to create user, type `0`. After, all student will be shown in a fashion style.